# Can we delete the dictionary from list of dictionaries whose all key: ' ' (empty string)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example:

```
reader = [{'Name': 'a', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}, {'Name': 'b', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}, {'Name': '', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}]
```

expected result:

```
reader = [{'Name': 'a', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}, {'Name': 'b', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}]
```

I want to remove last dictionary whose all values are '' empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
reader = [
    {'Amount': '12', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': '', 'Score': '', 'Updated Date': '', 'Company': 'neo', 'Email': '  ', 'Phone': '8002857', 'Fax': '', 'Created By': '', 'Name': '', 'Agent Owner': '', 'Source': '', 'Contact Name': 'XYZ'}, 
    {'Amount': '34', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': '', 'Score': '', 'Updated Date': '', 'Company': 'pop', 'Email': '', 'Phone': '8002857', 'Fax': '', 'Created By': '', 'Name': '', 'Agent Owner': '', 'Source': '', 'Contact Name': 'abc '}, 
    {'Amount': '', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': '', 'Score': '', 'Updated Date': '', 'Company': '', 'Email': '', 'Phone': '', 'Fax': '', 'Created By': '', 'Name': '', 'Agent Owner': '', 'Source': '', 'Contact Name': ''}
    ]        

reader = [row for row in reader if not all(v == '' for v in row.values())]
print(reader)
```

Output:

```
[
{'Amount': '12', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': '', 'Score': '', 'Updated Date': '', 'Company': 'neo', 'Email': '  ', 'Phone': '8002857', 'Fax': '', 'Created By': '', 'Name': '', 'Agent Owner': '', 'Source': '', 'Contact Name': 'XYZ'}, 
{'Amount': '34', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': '', 'Score': '', 'Updated Date': '', 'Company': 'pop', 'Email': '', 'Phone': '8002857', 'Fax': '', 'Created By': '', 'Name': '', 'Agent Owner': '', 'Source': '', 'Contact Name': 'abc '}
]
```

**UPDATE:**
The question has been edited. Here is an update to the above answer which uses the latest sample input/output in the question:

```
reader = [
    {'Name': 'a', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}, 
    {'Name': 'b', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}, 
    {'Name': '', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}
]
reader = [row for row in reader if not all(v == '' for v in row.values())]
print(reader)
```

Updated outputs:

```
[
{'Name': 'a', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}, 
{'Name': 'b', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate your `list` of `dict`s and check if each `dict` has any value that has length greater than 0:

```
reader = [
    dict_element
    for dict_element in reader
    if any(value for value in dict_element.values())
]
```

Notice that using `value` instead of `len(value) > 0` is equivalent since strings are casted to `False` only when the string is empty (`""`).

Answer (score 1):

use list comprehensions:

```
   reader = [_dict in reader if list(_dict.values())!=[''for i in len(_dict)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comprehension:

```
out = [l for l in reader if any(l.values())]
print(out)

# Output
[{'Name': 'a', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''},
 {'Name': 'b', 'Created Date': '', 'Updated By': ''}]
```

Answer (score 0):

using filter:

```
reader = list(filter(lambda x: any(x.values()), reader))
```